# Using ESC/POS print command to set height of the bar code

Tags: android, printing, barcode, epson

I am using the below code to print bar code. This prints the barcode but i am not able to set the height of the bar code.Below code prints the bar code with very small height.

public void PrintBarCode2(String Code) 
    {
        byte[] codeData =  Code.getBytes();

```
    ArrayList<Byte> command = new ArrayList<Byte>();

    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 0x1D));
    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 0x77));
    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 0x03));

    //Height
    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 0x1D));
    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 0x68));
    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 200));

    //Position
    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 0x1D));
    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 0x48));
    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 0x03));

    //Barcode
    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 0x1D));
    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 0x6B));
    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 0x06));
    for (byte byt : codeData) {
        command.add(Byte.valueOf(byt));
    }
    command.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 0x00));
    sendCommand(command);

}
```

Please help me.